# Calculate point, from point, at given angle

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry, trigonometry

I am attempting to create 'walls' using svg and JavaScript. I need to thicken the walls based on configured values and miter the corners appropriately at a given angle. The picture below depicts this.

The svg editor portion of my app allows me to draw Line 1 and Line 2 (in blue), and connect their end points at various angles. The image below shows a 90 degree angle, but the angle is user defined based on lines drawn, so it can be anything.

I have been able to do the math to determine a centriod point which allows me to bisect the user defined angle and create a miter line, which is shown below as a line with endpoints d and c. Given my calculations, I know the four green points and the green angle, along with a known, and configurable, distance between Line 1 and line 3 (undefined here, but lets assumes it 5 svg units), which btw will always be parallel.

In this example, the new wall consists of line 1 (the interior of the wall), line 3 (the exterior of the wall), and the miter line, which will connect line 1 and line 3. I assume the answer resides in the distance between lines 1 and 3, and the angle of the bisect line (endpoints d and c), but I cant pin down the math.

*How do I find x?*

Is there an easier way to go about this, or do I just know even less about trig than I thought I did (which by the way, is very little). thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythagoras: `A**2` + `B**2` = `C**2` - meaning (5 svg squared) + (5 svg squared) = (C -> X)squared. That gives you the distance from C->X and you have the green angle already.

You'll have to decide how precise you want to be (how many decimal places).

Say distance from line 1 to line 3 == 5;

```js
const A = 5;

const length = Math.sqrt((A * A) + (A * A));

console.log(length);
```

To extend the mitre line from C -> X:

- draw from C at 1/2 the green angle from Line 1 for the calculated length.

Half the green angle because the imaginary line between D and line 1 is a right angle to Line 1 and Line 3 (and the intersection of X by extension).

Comment: Hey Randy, thanks for the quick response. I think I am following, given that Pythagoras factors in because I'll always have a right angle from point C, down to line 3, regardless of the angle between lines 1 and 2. Correct? If that is the case, the only outstanding variable is the angle - but I dont see that referenced in the calculation. How is the angle of line C > X accounted for to reach point x?

Comment: @ErikR099 - please see my updated answer.